# Javascript Document isn't loading

Tags: javascript, html, express, socket.io

I have a webpage, and it is running `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
    <style>@import 'main.css'</style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id='svs'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, when I try to use `c = document.getElementById('svs')` in `main.js`, it just returns `null`. What am I doing wrong and how can I access `document` in `main.js`?

**Edit:**

I'm using `socket.io` and `express` and am sending `index.html` through `res.sendFile`.

I'm sending `main.css` and `main.js` through a folder with `express.static`.

Comment: Your `<script>`s should go either inside `<head>` or `<body>`. The answer to your question is that when main.js runs, the `<canvas>` doesn't exist yet. Move the main.js line right after the canvas, and it should work.

Comment: Yeah I could do that. One of the answers worked but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you can do is to put your code in `main.js` inside a function, and then add `onload` to `<body>`:

```
<body onload="yourfunction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

The template should be laid out in the following manner.Style and script tag should go under the wings of head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>@import 'main.css'</style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id='svs'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't fix by problem but I still moved the `style` and `script` tags under `<head>`